# Python's mechanize proxy support

Tags: python, mechanize

I have a question about python mechanize's proxy support. I'm making some web client script, and I would like to insert proxy support function into my script.

For example, if I have:

```
params = urllib.urlencode({'id':id, 'passwd':pw})
rq = mechanize.Request('http://www.example.com', params) 
rs = mechanize.urlopen(rq)
```

How can I add proxy support into my mechanize script?
Whenever I open this `www.example.com` website, i would like it to go through the proxy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use mechanize.Request.set_proxy(host, type) (at least as of 0.1.11)

assuming an http proxy running at localhost:8888

```
req = mechanize.Request("http://www.google.com")
req.set_proxy("localhost:8888","http")
mechanize.urlopen(req)
```

Should work.

Comment: What about Proxy Authentication

Answer (score 32):

I'm not sure whether that help or not but you can set proxy settings on [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) proxy browser.

```
br = Browser()
# Explicitly configure proxies (Browser will attempt to set good defaults).
# Note the userinfo ("joe:password@") and port number (":3128") are optional.
br.set_proxies({"http": "joe:password@myproxy.example.com:3128",
                "ftp": "proxy.example.com",
                })
# Add HTTP Basic/Digest auth username and password for HTTP proxy access.
# (equivalent to using "joe:password@..." form above)
br.add_proxy_password("joe", "password")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but that is mechanize.browser module, that is some different what i look for method, im looking for mechanize .urlopen method thanks

Comment: @harshal.c then what's the alternative?