# How do I use SSH proxy in mechanize module in python? (Is is possible to do so?)

Tags: python, mechanize

I couldn't find useful info on SSH proxy setting in mechanize, so I wonder if I can just set the proxy like this:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_proxies{“SSH": "11.11.11.11:22"}
```

Anybody knows? If this won't work, how do I make SSH proxy work with mechanize Browser?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997894/python-mechanize-proxy-support-question

Comment: @gimel: what category does SSH proxy fall into? HTTP proxy? So br.set_proxies{“HTTP": "127.0.0.1:7777"} would work, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I understood what you want here:

You can set up a proxy on machine B (http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyproxy/ is tiny) and then do SSH forwarding.

From machine A:

```
ssh -aNL 7777:localhost:8888 B
```

would establish a proxy on port 7777 on machine A that connects to port 8888 on machine B. If machine B has tinyproxy running on 8888, then you should be all set.

Comment: Does this mean br.set_proxies{“HTTP": "127.0.0.1:7777"} would work?

Comment: Correct, that should work provided you have a proxy running on B:8888.