# Using python mechanize and also urllib2 with random proxy support

Tags: python, python-2.7, proxy, urllib2, mechanize

I've got some http proxies for example:

```
123.123.123.123:2312
121.111.3.89:8080
111.133.1.111:23810
114.113.1.113:23812
111.133.1.114:23810
```

They all have the same username and password: `testuser` and `testpass`

I'm trying to incorporate **random** proxy support for the following:

```
import urllib2
import httplib
def check():
    try:
        urllib2.urlopen("", timeout = 60)
        return True
    except (IOError, httplib.HTTPException):
        return False
```

Also trying to incorporate it into the following:

```
import mechanize
def gethtml():
        post_url = ""
        browser = mechanize.Browser()
        browser.set_handle_robots(False)
        browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

        try:
            html = browser.open(post_url).read()
        except Exception:
            return
```

And also onto the similar:

```
import mechanize
def check2():
    post_url = ""
    browser = mechanize.Browser()
    browser.set_handle_robots(False)
    browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]
    parameters = {'page' : '1',
                  'sortorder' : 'asc'
                 }

    data = urllib.urlencode(parameters)

    try: 
        trans_array = browser.open(post_url,data).read().decode('UTF-8')
    except Exception:
        return
```

My biggest problem is everything that I've tried, I get the following two errors:

`httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 407: Proxy Authentication Required`

`HTTPError: HTTP Error 407: Proxy Authentication Required`

Is anyone able to help me create some working examples, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: So your just asking how to use proxy with urllib2 and mechanize? I think there are plenty of tutorials there. If you have some error that you can not fix - try to post the actual code that gives you this error and someone may help you

Answer (score 1):

"Random proxy support" with `mechanize`?  Would that just be [regular mechanize proxy stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997894/pythons-mechanize-proxy-support), but with a randomly-picked proxy from your list of proxies?

If so, you can try this:

```
import mechanize
import random

proxies = [
    '123.123.123.123:2312',
    '121.111.3.89:8080'
    '111.133.1.111:23810',
    '114.113.1.113:23812',
    '111.133.1.114:23810',
    ]
rand_proxy = random.choice(proxies)

browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_proxies({'http': rand_proxy})
browser.add_proxy_password('testuser', 'testpass')
```