# python Mechanize proxy and user authentication settings

Tags: python

How to add set proxy and add user name and password ( proxy authentication)? In my home I have:

> proxy 12.12.12.1:8080
>
> username = 123acd
>
> pass = password.

Comment: this could help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997894/pythons-mechanize-proxy-support

Answer (score -1):

I think this will do it:

`br.set_proxies({"http": "123acd:password@12.12.12:8080",})`

Just place the line somewhere before `br.open()`.

I found this here: http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

Btw: *If these are your real login data, you should change them ;)*

Hope this helps you

Comment: This is not working for me. There is an error of proxy authentication is required.

Comment: Well this is from the official docs... Are the login data valid?

Comment: Or adding `br.add_proxy_password("123acd", "password")` below `br.set_proxies({"http": "123acd:password@12.12.12:8080",})`?